# Connected Model on MVC HttpPost Methods

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

When rendering the view after a form post, when the form has model errors, and I need to render the form again, but with all the changed fields, how can I attach the model to the dbContext so that I can display reference properties?

Currently the view will error out in that scenario because it being rendered with a model constructed solely based on formdata, and it cannot display the related reference properties.

Summary: View that displays reference properties along with standard model fields, receives null reference error when rendering the view after an httppost of the model.

Comment: You just need to rebuild the relevant portion of the model again.  This is a pretty common scenario with things like dropdownlists, where they're initially passed to the view but are no longer available when redisplaying the form, so they have to be fetched again.

Comment: @john-h I was hoping for a simple way to "attach" the copy from the Request.Form to the dbContext, so that Lazy Loading would work.

Comment: I'm using  `_db.Entry(entity).Reference(a => a.Property).Load();` for each property that the view needs. It just seems like there should be a method to enable lazy loads.